# Predefined Preprocessor Directive in NDK not working

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, c-preprocessor

C++ Header for class **XYZ.h**

```
//Default constructor will be used in multiple platforms
XYZ();

#ifdef __ANDROID__

//parametrized constructors should be used only in Android platform
XYZ(DirectorBase *director);

#endif //End __ANDROID__
```

- __ANDROID__ does not work and it removes parameterised constructor when compiled through NDK.
- Where in lot of blogs I can see that NDK have predefined preprocessor __ANDROID__
- How to make this work?
  Where some code only should be work in android and ignored in other platforms.

Comment: Please tell us which version of Android and the NDK you're using.

Comment: I'm going to assume that you have an Android-specific makefile, or at least a makefile that contains Android-specific parts. So it would be easy to just add any define you want there, and then check for those in your code.

Comment: @Michael: Can you be more specific about how to achieve this, about creating defines in android make file ?

Comment: @erapert: I am using Android NDK, Revision 10e,
 to be more specific 'GNU Make 3.81' 64bit ubuntu

Comment: Just add `-DWHATEVER` to your `LOCAL_CFLAGS`

Comment: so, in order to use #ifdef \_\_ANDROID\_\_ do I have to add LOCAL_CFLAGS:=-DANDROID